# How to start ColdFusion in Ubuntu 2.0

Tags: coldfusion, ubuntu-20.04

I installed the dev version of ColdFusion on Ubuntu 2.0 and now I cant find how to start it.
I am very beginner with coldfusion - it is just my first try at this.

It installed stuff to
/opt/coldfusionaddonservices

**Edit
How I installed it:**

I went to

https://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/download-trial/try.html
I downloaded the Linux version of it. It downloaded a file called ColdFusion_2018_APIManager_WWEJ_linux64.bin

then I ran ./ColdFusion_2018_APIManager_WWEJ_linux64.bin
This installed stuff in my

/opt/coldfusionaddonservices

There I have this files:

```
Adobe_ColdFusion_2021_Add-on_Services_Install_04_29_2021_19_01_02.log*
cf_app.ico*
cfjetty*
etc/
exampleAnalysis/
example-DIH/
exampledocs/
jre/
lib/
logs/
modules/
notice.txt*
resources/
solr/
start.ini*
start.jar*
webapps/
work/
```

Comment: You want the [CF Server download](https://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads.html#cf2021productdownloads), not the API Manager  (monitoring tool). Look for the link titled "ColdFusion (2021 release) - Developer Edition" (the "trial" version works too, as it reverts to the Dev edition after 30 days)

Comment: ColdFusion (2021 release) - Developer Edition (Free) link takes me to https://www.adobe.com/ro/products/coldfusion/download-trial/try.html Here I fill all the fields and I click Download button at the bottom of the page. This does not downloads anything but takes me to this page: https://www.adobe.com/ro/products/coldfusion/download-trial/get-started.html Hereagain - I dont see no download button for the CF Server. I might be blind or smth..

Comment: You have to sign in to download the installer from Adobe, you'll get emails from them afterwards trying to sell the server to you. I posted on your FB request, but you'll get started far faster using CommandBox to get the server running w/o all this jumping through hoops. https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox

Comment: I am logged in - there is no download starting. Maybe I selected an option which disables downloading?

Comment: Ad-blocker software can interfere as well. That said, @AdrianJMoreno's suggestion about Commandbox is a good one. Pretty easy to use

Answer (score 3):

I just did some searching and found this reference - [ColdFusion Installation](https://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/tutorial/coldfusion_installation.cfm)

Basically, there should be a `bin` directory under your installation. Somewhere like `{cfroot}\cfusion\bin` where `{cfroot}` is your ColdFusion installation root directory. Inside that directory there are several files.

Run the following command from that directory to start ColdFusion: `./coldfusion start`

To stop ColdFusion use `./coldfusion stop`

To restart ColdFusion use `./coldfusion restart`

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at all resources. I just searched for that dir and I dont have it (sudo find / -type d -name "cfusion"). I will update how I installed it in the mai post. Maybe this is wrong.

Comment: You'll probably see that directory once you install the cf server (rather than api manager). Though not sure you'll need to start it manually... On windows the installer sets the cf server to start automatically. Don't know about ubuntu, but still good to info to know

Comment: THANK YOU!  So simple, yet so hard to find online. You saved a few strands of my hair.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks I downloaded the wrong CF
To download the server you need to go to this page

https://www.adobe.com/ro/products/coldfusion/download-trial/get-started.html#

Then at the bottom there is the

Interested in trying our Adobe ColdFusion Express Edition ?
Windows 64, Mac, WAR 64
And you choose MAC for Linux.

Comment: As an update for readers who may find this in the future, there are a few things to note about Alex's answer. First, the link offered has /ro within it, meaning it's a link for Romanian content at Adobe.com. Whether you leave that in or take it out, the page you are taken to is one that he would have been offered AFTER filling out a form on another page (his offers a link to "retry download"), which will not help if you did not come through the previous page, which is https://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/download-trial/try.html. The offers options for various CF installers.